# Atualizar página em intervalo de tempo

Tags: php, codeigniter

Preciso setar a meta:

```
meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30"
```

Entretanto estou utilizando CodeIgniter e não consigo fazer. Tentei:

```
$this->output->set_header('refresh:30;url=minhapagina.php');
```

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2):

Coloque direto na sua View pode até configurar se vai precisar ou não da mesma!
Assim

```
public function index(){
        $data['stsRefresh'] = true;
        $this->load->view('Arquivos/index', $data);
}
```

E na sua View

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    if (isset($stsRefresh)){
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">';
    }
?>
<form action="/arquivos/do_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

***Referência***

- [A Fully Baked PHP Framework](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)